# Matlab index with specific values using loop

Tags: matlab, loops, vector, indexing

I know how to write the program with a given number of entries, but not when if the number of entries are n:. Basically I think I need a loop but I can't get it to work properly.

---

This is a code that works fine when having 3 entries. % is what I put in. I want to create a vector with specific position and values, this is a example how the vector would look like:

```
X = [1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;99;0;0;0;0;99]
```

and the code for it:

```
n1 = input('Determine value for case:'); %n1 = 1

n2 = input('Determine value for case:'); %n2 = 15

n3 = input('Determine value for case:'); %n3 = 20

X = zeros(20,1);

X(n1) = input('Determine position '); %1

X(n2) = input('Determine position '); %99

X(n3) = input('Determine position '); %99
```

---

But for n entries, I need a loop I figured. (the vector may still be 20x1)

```
    for n = 1:entries (%entries are 3, so 3 loops)
    n = n+1

    n = input('Determine value for case :');

    X =zeros(20,1);
    X(n) = input('Determine position:')

    end
```

But I can't just get it to work

thanks in advance

Comment: No need for `n=n+1`, for loop already does this when you say `for n=1:entries`. Why re-initialize X inside the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I think that you can fix your loop as follows:

```
  entries = 3;
  X =zeros(20,1);

  for ni = 1:entries 

    n = input('Determine value for case :');
    X(n) = input('Determine position:');

  end
```

Comment: That worked as intended but backwards, so a bit of modification and it was okey. thanks! Basically I wanted a vector of a size, and be able to depending on n values put specific values at specific positions within that vector.